# Marketpress Productlist loop fetching only one product

Tags: php, wordpress

this is my mp_productlist.php

```
<?php get_header();?>
                <div class="content_mid">
                    <?php if ( have_posts() ) : ?>
                    <?php while ( have_posts() ) : the_post(); ?>
                    <div class="post thin">
                         <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>">
                             <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2></a>
<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark" title="Permanent Link to <?php the_title_attribute(); ?>"><?php if ( function_exists( 'add_theme_support' ) ) the_post_thumbnail(); ?></a>
                        <h3><?php mp_product_price(true) ?></h3><?php mp_buy_button(true, 'single')?>
                    </div>
                    <?php endwhile;?>
                    <?php else : ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <!--end post-->
                </div>
<?php get_footer();?>
```

and this is what I'm getting http://angelov.ga/old/store/products/

it's only fetching one products instead of the two test products I have

thanks in advance

Comment: I am using the same code in my mp_category.php and it's working with multiple prodcuts. I am getting so frustrated

Comment: As far as I can see it's fetching two different products with the same image.

Comment: that's because it's a test site and it's got 2 products with the same image. thing is... it needs to be like the "PRODUCTS" in the main navbar. It should display all the products in the store as in the "PRODUCTS" in the navbar

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just did a simple workaround and categorized everything in the category ALL and I have subcategories for each supplement thing and changed the BROWSE PRODUCTS thing to /category/all